# When doing parallel testing with selenium grid, how are folders (used by each browser) created?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm running tests in selenium grid. Each node runs 1 browser. Some of the tests require file downloads to a network drive. Right now I have one download directory in the drive (shared across nodes and hub) that is used by all browsers. I was wondering if this is the right approach or should there be a download folder for each node, that way, let's say if 2 download tests are running in parallel and are downloading the same file, the file ends up in each of their folder?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be triggering downloads via Selenium (I am guessing that you are using the profile mechanism in firefox, and setting default download location manually in IE to get this done). You should instead see if you can leverage the approach suggested in [this](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) blog.